# Не меняется application.icon при передаче параметров программе

Tags: delphi, pascal

Мне необходимо менять иконку программы в runtime.

Реализую в принципе банально:

```
Application.Icon.LoadFromFile(extractfilepath(application.exename) + '\myicon.ico');
```

И все работает корректно, но только если не передавать параметры программе.
К примеру, если я запускаю свою программу с дополнительными параметрами, к примеру "Project1.exe another", то иконка уже не хочет меняться. Просто ничего не происходит.

Пробовал кучу разных методов, ничего не помогает.
Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

UPD - выяснил, что данное поведение появляется только при  запуске с ярлыка, если запускать к примеру через cmd - То все ок.

Comment: Какая версия Delphi?

Comment: Embarcadero 10.3

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы используете ярлык, то иконка используется из ярлыка - это штатное поведение Windows.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Так что параметры здесь ни при чем.

Comment: Спасибо. Да, я уже сам догадался, что дело в ярлыке :) Можно ли как-то программно отследить, что запуск идет с ярлыка? И есть ли способ поменять иконку если запуск с ярлыка был?

Answer (score 0):

Чтож, жаль, что никто не знает решения.
Тогда отвечу на часть своего же вопроса по поводу того, как отследить, что запуск был произведен с ярлыка.

```
function GetShortcutName(out LinkName: string): Boolean;
var
  si: TStartupInfo;
begin
  Result := False;
 FillChar(si, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), 0);
 GetStartupInfo(si);
 if (si.dwFlags and  $800  ) <> 0 then
 begin
  Result := True;
  LinkName := si.lpTitle;
 end;
end;
```

Далее вызываем:

```
var
  sLink: string;
begin

  if GetShortcutName(sLink) then
  caption:='run from Shortcut - '+ sLink
  else caption:='Not run from shortcut.';
```